# How can i list all user registered on my website and have pagination

Tags: php, pagination

How can i list all user registered on my website.

If i have 300 users, i want to list only 10 on a page and list next 10 on other page..

- I want the user to have an image
- I want to list post added by the user
- I want to list the number of  trailer's added by the user (custom post type - trailere)( if i click on the number it shoud get me on user page)
- I want to list the number of  subtitrari's added by the user (custom post type - subtitrari )( if i click on the number it shoud get me on user page)

This is wath i have try, it list ok but how can

```
<table class="tut">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><b>Poza</b></th>
            <th><b>Name</b></th>
            <th><b>Inregistrat</b></th>
            <th><b>Nume</b></th>
            <th><b>User Level</b></th>
            <th><b>User Role</b></th>
            <th><b>Vezi Profil</b></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="the-list" class="list:user">
                                <?php 
          $wp_user_search = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, display_name FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY ID");
          foreach ( $wp_user_search as $userid ) {
            $user_id = (int) $userid->ID;
            $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
                                                $user_picture =  get_avatar($userid->ID, 40);
            $formid = $user_info->formid;
            $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
            echo '<th>' . $user_picture .  '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . $user_info->display_name . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . $user_info->user_registered . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . $user_info->nickname . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . $user_info->user_level . '</th>';
            echo '<th>'; if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) { foreach ( $user->roles as $role ) echo $role; } echo '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . $userid->ID . '</th>';
                                                echo '</tr>';
          } 
                                        ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th><b>Poza</b></th>
            <th><b>Name</b></th>
            <th><b>Inregistrat</b></th>
            <th><b>Nume</b></th>
            <th><b>User Level</b></th>
            <th><b>User Role</b></th>
            <th><b>Vezi Profil</b></th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

use wp user query instead your own check the codex for more info [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
```